# Extjs Creating a tagfield without the list

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox

I know this might not be the way it was intended to be used, but I'm going to ask anyway:

*Is there a way to create a `tagfield` without the drop down list?*

What we have is a custom control which is a combination of a tagfield and an itemSelector. The itemSelector is inside a panel which appears via a toggle button. After we have selected some values, we hide the panel and those values get selected in the tagfield. We are essentially not using the tagfield's combobox properties, but we want to keep the ability to remove any records by pressing the "x" beside the records. Is there a configuration or other way to block the tagfield from showing the drop down list when it is clicked?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IMO easiest way is to override `extend` method (it might be empty) and set `hideTrigger` to `true`:

```
{
    xtype: 'tagfield',
    store: store,
    expand: Ext.emptyFn,
    hideTrigger: true
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mmvg1bL2/

Comment: Tested it this morning and it works. Should have thought of it myself... Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

there's also `triggerOnClick` boolean config option ([6.0.1](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Tag-cfg-triggerOnClick), [5.1.2](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.2-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Tag-cfg-triggerOnClick))
which achieves the same; also to be used with `hideTrigger: true`